# Robotic/Stuttering audio in VLC on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, audio, vlc-media-player, avi

VLC 2.2.4, macOS 10.12.3, MacBook Pro 2015 15"

When playing .avi files in VLC, the audio holds and stutters. Not all the time, at various points throughout the video. I've changed the sound output to no avail.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the holding/stuttering always happen at the same point? Have you checked what other software is running that might be requiring more CPU at those times?